# SQLite API to determine size of WAL file

Tags: sqlite, wal

Is there any api within SQLite which would return the current size of the WAL journal file? I need to check for its size periodically and perform some actions if it exceeds a certain limit. I am currently using system calls like stat() from my c++ program to achieve this, but just wondering if any inbuilt platform-independent method is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the `-wal` file is not visible as far as the database API is concerned.